# Undersampling large dataset under specific conditon applied to other column in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I currently working with a large dataset (about 40 coulmns and tens of thousans of rows) and i would like to undersample it to be able to work with it more easily.
For the undersampling, unlike the [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) method from pandas that resample according to timedelta, I'm trying to specify conditons on other columns to determine the data points to keep.
I'm not sure it's so clear but for example, let's say I have 3 columns (index, time and temperature) like as followed:

[image: example table before resampling][image: corresponding plot for data before resampling]

Now for the resampling, I would like to keep a data point every 1s or every 2°C, the resulting dataset would look like this:

[image: example table after resampling][image: corresponding plot after resampling]

I couldn't find a simple way of doing this with pandas. The only way would be to iterate over the rows but it was very slow because of the size of my datasets.
I though about using the [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) method but of course it can only determine the difference on a specified period, same for [pct_change](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) that could have been use to keep only the points in the regions were the variations are maximal to undersample.

Thanks in advance if you have any suggestions on how to proceed with this resampling.

Comment: It is safe to assume that there is always a sample every 0.1 seconds?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the sample rate may vary depending on the recording conditions configured on the device.

Comment: And may even vary within one single dataset.